# String model references must be of the form 'app_label.ModelName' error while adding a Foreign Key field to model

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys

I have an app *customer* inside *company/sales/* with app_label as 'company.sales.customer'.
This app contains a model Customer in models.py.

I want this model to be linked as a foreign key in another app 'orders'.

models.py of 'orders':

```
from django.db import models
 
class Order(models.Model):
    party = models.ForeignKey('company.sales.customer.Customer', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    --other fields--
```

apps.py of 'customer':

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class CustomerConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'company.sales.customer'
    label = 'company.sales.customer'
```

settings.py :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
----,
'company.sales.customer'
]
```

On running `python manage.py makemigrations`, I get this error :

```
ValueError: Invalid model reference 'company.sales.customer.Customer'. String model references must be of the form 'app_label.ModelName'.
```

Comment: Likely the `app_label` of your model is `customer`, so `'customer.Customer'`. You can check this with `Customer._meta.app_label` in the Django shell...